# Is the sum of a Kähler metric and a balanced metric balanced?

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, riemannian-geometry

Let X  be a compact complex manifold, and let $u$ be a Kähler metric and $v$ a balanced metric.
My question is about the metric $u+v$, is it balanced?

More precisely, is the operator $*$ of  Hodge on $(X, u+v)$ different from that of $(X, u)$ and $(X, v)$?

Comment: Is this an exercise question?

Comment: No i need it in my research

Comment: can you also write what you think about this? Do you think it should be true? Have you written down Hodge star operators? Please add it here :)

Comment: yes it's the Hodge star operators, i think that's true but i'm not sur